# Inner Hits isn't working ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good Day:

I'm using ElasticSearch/NEST to query against nested objects. What I realize is that my nested object is empty however, the parent is being returned despite there being now match.

```
ISearchResponse<Facility> responses = await this._elasticClient.SearchAsync<Facility>(a => a.Query(q =>
                  q.Bool(b =>
                            b.Must(m =>
                                m.Nested(n =>
                                    n.Query(nq =>
                                            nq.Term(t =>t.Field(f => f.Reviews.First().UserId).Value(user.Id))
                                            ).InnerHits(ih => ih.From(0).Size(1).Name("UserWithReview"))
                                 )
                             )
                       )

            ));
```

When I look at the generated query, I"m even more confused what is happening:

```
Successful low level call on POST: /dev/doc/_search?typed_keys=true
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.9806442
# Request:
{}
```

As you can see the request is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined the nested query with all the properties needed; it's missing the `Path` property, which tells Elasticsearch which document field (i.e. path) to execute the query on. Looking at the rest of the query, it looks like this should be the `Reviews` property

```
ISearchResponse<Facility> responses =
    await this._elasticClient.SearchAsync<Facility>(a => a
        .Query(q => q
            .Bool(b => b
                .Must(m => m
                    .Nested(n => n
                        .Path(f => f.Reviews) // <-- missing
                        .Query(nq => nq
                            .Term(t => t
                                .Field(f => f.Reviews.First().UserId)
                                .Value(user.Id)
                            )
                        )
                        .InnerHits(ih => ih.From(0).Size(1).Name("UserWithReview"))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```